# cmder/conEmu hotkeys how to set up for for directory movements

Tags: conemu, cmder, clink

I would like to define the following keys in Cmder:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> -> move to parent directory (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>)

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> -> move to previous directory (the one I was in before the last cd)

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> -> move to next directory

Any help ?

Comment: Which version of Cmder are you using? I haven't found in my version any directory-movement hotkeys.

Comment: latest version. I don't understand what you're asking, if they were such hotkeys defined already I wouldn't be asking this ...

Comment: Please post a link to your version.

Comment: the 'download full' at cmder.net

Comment: That's the one I'm using and I cannot find anything like that in Settings / Keys & Macro, and the combo ctrl+alt+u only produces an accented character. The only solution I can think of is to use [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) to automate the [pushd and popd commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushd_and_popd). If this is an acceptable solution, I can post it as an answer.

Comment: ctrl+alt+u switch to the directory above, if it doesn't work for you maybe clink did not install properly. The hotkeys are defined in vendors\clink\clink_inputrc_base but I don't know how to define alt+up there. Autohotkeys is not acceptable thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said AutoHotKeys is not acceptable, it is difficult to move to previous and next directory, but it can be done. I have added one way to achieve it, but moving up the directory is pretty simple.

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> for settings and goto the Keys and Macros Section.
- Select the Macros from the dropdown.
- Select an empty Macro and Assign <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>
- Next in the GUI Macro, set the value as `print("cd ..\n")`. This will set the go back to parent directory. The `\n` in the print statement mimics an <kbd>Enter</kbd> keypress.

One way you can achieve to go back to the previous directory is by setting pushd as an alias to cd. For example, if you are using [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell), you can set the alias like this: `remove-item alias:\cd ; set-alias "cd" "pushd"`

Now, you can set the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> key to `print("popd\n")` to go back to the previous location.

Comment: "Select an empty Macro and Assign Alt+Up" .. I am unable to do this, I can only capture Up but not Alt+Up .. did it work for you ? I don't want to override the default "Up" behaviour of history scrolling thx

Comment: There are drop downs above the gui macro entry field, just select <kbd>alt</kbd> from there.